# Use Susy with Codekit

Tags: susy-compass

Hi i try to get going susy with codekit. I have installed the latest codekit version (1.26) aside i have also installed the latest versions of sass and compass via the terminal. Within Codekit i switched to use the external version of compass installed in the terminal. According to the Codekit dev it is necessary at the moment because for compass extensions the internal codekit compass version is external, which leads to some dependencies issues. then i have downloaded the latest zipped version of susy from github.in the the config.rb file of my project i have set a require for the plain unzipped version of susy:

```
require "/Users/danton/Documents/Coding/Templates/Compass/susy-d6a2a1f/lib/susy.rb";
```

and within my scss file:

```
@import 'susy';
```

in my wrapper div for the whole page i've set:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    @include container;
    @include susy-grid-background;
    @include bleed;

}
```

Bleed is the mixin Eric has posted on here. Till there everything looks good and ok. I get the susy grid background and with the bleed mixin the elements are stretched over the whole page width. But when i try to add a "span-columns" codekit is spitting out an error on compile:

```
error style.scss (Line 24 of _layout.scss: Undefined mixin 'span-columns'.)
```

the code related to susy in the _layout.scss looks like that:

```
$total-columns: 24;
$column-width: 4em;
$gutter-width: 1em;
$grid-padding: $gutter-width;  // 1em

@mixin bleed($padding: $grid-padding, $sides: left right) {
  @if $sides == 'all' {
    margin: - $padding;
    padding: $padding;
  } @else {
    @each $side in $sides {
       margin-#{$side}: - $padding;
       padding-#{$side}: $padding;
    }
  }
}

.testcol { @include span-columns(18,24); }
```

Do i have to install susy in the terminal too instead of linking just to the uncompressed zip file or what to do best to get things going. still unsure a bit what is causing the error on compile? my used code? codekit? susy? if anyone has a hint how to get things working it would be nice. thanks in advance. r.

Comment: I've installed susy within the terminal too, but the same effect turns out on compile; codekit is returning the same error on the span-columns mixin.

Comment: Ok i found the reason why my setup behaved odd. I've included the susy setting in a partial file _grid.scss as well as the the include for the span-columens for one of my classes (as a quick test - wanted to keep the structure within the grid partial). that was the only reason. havent given much of a thought cuz i thought all partial content is compiled within the main scss file anyway. but as soon as i put the span-columns include within the main scss file style.scss everything worked like a charm. much fiddling over the last few days but finally working now. ;)  cheers